# RESTFul: How should a POST request body format be specified?

Tags: rest

I'm working a RESTFul API and have a POST method that will allow either JSON or CSV body content.

What is best way to handle this? Should URL routing/parameters be used (such as `/resource/json` or `/resource/?type=json`), or through headers (so URL would just be `/resource` and a header would specify json or csv)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way according to W3C (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) is to use the Content Type header to specify the correct type.

- For json it would be `Content-Type: application/json`
- For a text CSV it would be `Content-Type: text/csv`

Avoid using url params.  While this is not 'non-restful' it's not the recommended method and smells of amateur hour.  Even worse is creating a new 'resource' which is just a representation of an existing resource.

Comment: This is missing the other important part: the `Accept` header.

Comment: @Evert while I recommend always sending an Accept header, isn't needed to inform the server how to process the body being sent--which was the scope of OP.

Comment: @Evert also, the Accept header is also optional 'may be specified'. `If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types.`  and the server can reply in it's default.  Technically  Content-type is optional and can be guessed, but the recent RFC that superseeds  rfc1341 added language to strongly discourage guessing Content Type

Comment: Ray:  I thought the question was about requesting a certain media-type with `GET`. Completely glossed over the "posting" part. Hence my mistake.